# Lubuntu transparent background reset

Tags: lubuntu

On Lubuntu.

I am trying to use the transparent background options in lxterminal and terminator to have them provide "fake transparency" as in using my background image as the background. This works perfectly when i configure my settings, however when i relog back in the background image in the applications is suddenly the default lubuntu background image. The background image on my desktop is still the correct image though.

I am running the default Lubuntu installation, LXDE with OpenBox.
Any idea what may be causing this and what i can do to fix it?